# Convert string to number in PHP

Tags: php

How can I convert `string(6) "8,9,10"` to `8,9,10` or `'8,9,10'` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set all to int by `intval` function

```
$comma_separated = array_map('intval',explode(",", '8,9,10'));
```

Answer (score 1):

We also need to use implode function

```
$comma_separated = array_map('intval',explode(",", '8,9,10'));
echo implode(',',$comma_separated);
```

Comment: I can accept only one answer but yours works too. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code to change string number into int number.

```
$myVar= (int)$comma_separated;
var_dump($myVar);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Sorry. `var_dump` gave me `int(8)` only.

Comment: try this way .
$string = "1,2,3, bla";
$ids = array_flip(array_flip(explode(',', $string)));
var_dump($ids);